# difference between 'Class<?>' and 'Object' as argument of method

Tags: java

Assume i want to have a method that get an object of any type in my application to validate all fields it has (each object has different fields with different types) and wrap it to a message. so the method input argument would be instance of any object

Now my question is :
what's the difference between having this input argument as an `Object` or `Class<?>` ?

as i know `?` means 'any type or class' and 'Object' is a super type in java .

i appreciate if Someone could explain me in which cases better to use this :

```
public validateAndConvertAnyObject(Object obj) {
    // compute and return a message
}
```

and when it's better to use this ?

```
public validateAndConvertAnyObject(Class<?> obj) {
    // compute and return a message
}
```

Comment: I do not have the impression that you have actually written code yourself to find out. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: thanks to anyone who tried to help but i did't get my answer , i stopped posting because some friends point negative without pondering that my question is about usage of these two type method calling and it's not about differences. i mark the first answer by the way @Zabuza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't specify a return type in your method.
It is not valid.

Second, these two parameters are totally different.

```
public validateAndConvertAnyObject(Object obj)
```

can accept any object.

While     `public validateAndConvertAnyObject(Class<?> obj)`

can accept any class.

The equivalent of

```
public validateAndConvertAnyObject(Object obj)
```

with generic would be :

```
public <T> void validateAndConvertAnyObject(T obj){
```

After compilation and type erasure, these provide the same compiled class.
So in this example, using `Object` makes more sense as more explicit.

To convert an instance to another class with reflection, generally, you pass the target class :

```
public <T> T validateAndConvertAnyObject(Object obj, Class<T> targetClass){
    ...//processing on obj

}
```

And you could use it :

```
MyObject myObject = ...;
MyOtherClass myOtherClass = validateAndConvertAnyObject(myObject, MyOtherClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first method can be called with any object as an argument, eg `"foo"`, `42` or `Integer.class`. The second one will only accept class objects, eg `"foo".getClass()` or `String.class`

Answer (score 0):

## What is the difference between `Class<?>` and `Object`

### `Object`

This takes the instance as a parameter

### `Class<?>`

This takes a class as a parameter

## Example

Object could be equal to `String`, and for a similar result you could have `Class<?>` equal to `java.lang.String`.

## Confusion

Technically, you could pass an instance of `Class<?>` as an `Object`, which adds confusion, which is a good reason to use `Class<?>` instead, as it prevents mixing up the instance and it's class.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` actually represents an **instance** of a **created object** like:

```
String text = "Hello World!";
Object textAsObj = (Object) text;
```

Whereas `Class` only represents the **class** of objects, it has **no connection** to an actual instance of this class:

```
Class<?> textClass = Class.forName("java.util.String");
```

So you should probably use the `Object` variant if you want to access specific values of an **instance**. You can, at anytime, retrieve the class from an `Object` using the `getClass` method:

```
String text = "Hello World!";
Class<String> textClass = text.getClass();
```

And here is an example how you could use that to access a field of a given `Object`:

```
Person person = new Person("John Doe");
Class<Person> personClass = person.getClass();

Field nameField = personClass.getDeclaredField("name");
String name = (String) nameField.get(person);
```